# Difficulty changing blue color to transparent

Tags: html, css, svg, transparent

How do I change the blue to transparent? https://jsfiddle.net/o64znkc5/

That is all I am trying to do in the code.

How am I able to do that?

It is asking me to provide more information but that is everything.

I can't figure out how to do it.

[image]

```css
.exit {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: circle(50%);

}

.exit svg {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <g id="exit">
            <title>exit</title>
            <path fill="red" d="m-101.116-101.116a143 143 0 11202.232 202.232a143 143 0 01-202.232-202.232zzzz" />
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="113" />
            <path fill="blue" d="m-101.116-101.116m169.705 11.313a113 113 0 00-137.178 0l68.589 68.59zm-158.392 21.214a113 113 0 000 137.178l68.59-68.589zm21.214 158.392a113 113 0 00137.178 0l-68.589-68.59zm158.392-21.214a113 113 0 000-137.178l-68.59 68.589z" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </button>

      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>

      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it now is not possible filing it `transparent` or `none` although you can fill it white as the background.

```css
.exit {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: circle(50%);

}

svg,use{fill:blue}



button:hover svg, 
button:hover use
{fill:white}
```

```html
<button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <g id="exit">
            <title>exit</title>
            <path fill="red" d="m-101.116-101.116a143 143 0 11202.232 202.232a143 143 0 01-202.232-202.232zzzz" />
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="113" fill="red" />
            <path d="m-101.116-101.116m169.705 11.313a113 113 0 00-137.178 0l68.589 68.59zm-158.392 21.214a113 113 0 000 137.178l68.59-68.589zm21.214 158.392a113 113 0 00137.178 0l-68.589-68.59zm158.392-21.214a113 113 0 000-137.178l-68.59 68.589z" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </button>

      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>

      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
```

However if you need it to be transparent I would change the code like so: I'm using a mask made from the two paths to pierce the red base. Please observe that  in the mask what is meant to be a hole is filled white while the visible part is keeped black.

```css
.exit {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: circle(50%);

}

svg,use{fill:blue}

button:hover svg,
button:hover use
{fill:none}
```

```html
  <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <g id="exit">
            <title>exit</title>
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="113"  />
            <path fill="red" mask="url(#m)"  d="m-101.116-101.116a143 143 0 11202.232 202.232a143 143 0 01-202.232-202.232zzzz" />
            <mask id="m">
            <path fill="white"  d="m-101.116-101.116a143 143 0 11202.232 202.232a143 143 0 01-202.232-202.232zzzz" />
            <path fill="black" d="m-101.116-101.116m169.705 11.313a113 113 0 00-137.178 0l68.589 68.59zm-158.392 21.214a113 113 0 000 137.178l68.59-68.589zm21.214 158.392a113 113 0 00137.178 0l-68.589-68.59zm158.392-21.214a113 113 0 000-137.178l-68.59 68.589z" />
              </mask>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </button>

      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>

      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
```

One more observation: for consistency I would use only `<use>` elements inside the buttons by making the svg element invisible with width="0" height="0" and position:absolute;

Also you don't need the width="100%" inside the svg elements inside the buttons. By default they would be 100% wide

```css
.exit {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}

svg[width = "0"]{
position:absolute;
left:-100em;}

use{fill:blue}
button:hover use
{fill:none}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
          <g id="exit">
            <title>exit</title>
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="113"  />
            <path fill="red" mask="url(#m)"  d="m-101.116-101.116a143 143 0 11202.232 202.232a143 143 0 01-202.232-202.232zzzz" />
            <mask id="m">
            <path fill="white"  d="m-101.116-101.116a143 143 0 11202.232 202.232a143 143 0 01-202.232-202.232zzzz" />
            <path fill="black" d="m-101.116-101.116m169.705 11.313a113 113 0 00-137.178 0l68.589 68.59zm-158.392 21.214a113 113 0 000 137.178l68.59-68.589zm21.214 158.392a113 113 0 00137.178 0l-68.589-68.59zm158.392-21.214a113 113 0 000-137.178l-68.59 68.589z" />
              </mask>
          </g>
        </svg>



<button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
       <svg viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>

      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>

      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg  viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
      
      
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
      
      <!--You can add as many buttons you want using rhe same structure-->
      
     <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
      
      
     <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
```

Comment: My Code Example: https://i.imgur.com/jKn1nAU.png https://jsfiddle.net/o64znkc5/  ////// Your Code 3 Example: https://i.imgur.com/aqKUmRX.png https://jsfiddle.net/2kb3qr0m/ In your code example there, the svgs are pushed over to the right, how would that be fixed? Are you able to see what I am referring to?

Comment: You can add `position: absolute;` for the first svg the one with width="0" height="0" You can also add `left: -100em` to throw it out of the window

Comment: How come you removed button from the first svg?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you. There is no button in any svg

Comment: <button> <svg width="0" height="0"> You removed button from there, how come?

Comment: As I've commented in my answer: for consistency I would use only <use> elements inside the buttons. The first svg is needed for the use elements. You can keep it inside id so desired.

Comment: Adding button to your 3rd Code example messes up the code. Seen Here: How would that be fixed? Updated link: https://jsfiddle.net/vx7btf0g/

Comment: In your jsfiddle in the first button you have the invisible (width="0" height="0") svg element. As I've mentioned before, inside the button I'm using the svg with a  <use> element.

Comment: Please take a look at the third example where I've added 2 more buttons

Comment: The button attribute is not needed to be stated on this one? <svg width="0" height="0"> How come? Why is that?

Comment: You have the first svg just to build the group (#exit) to be used for the <use> elements. It has a width of 0 and a height of 0

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me, now I understand it better.

Comment: I added a hover here to only the "X": https://jsfiddle.net/vp8shwf3/ How do I make the blue transparent using mask, like how you did it, but with no hover on the circle?

Comment: Is that able to be done? That seems very difficult to figure out how to do.

Answer (score 0):

`<path fill="blue">` to `<path fill="transparent">` on line 7

`<path fill="transparent" d="m-101.116-101.116m169.705 11.313a113 113 0 00-137.178 0l68.589 68.59zm-158.392 21.214a113 113 0 000 137.178l68.59-68.589zm21.214 158.392a113 113 0 00137.178 0l-68.589-68.59zm158.392-21.214a113 113 0 000-137.178l-68.59 68.589z" />`

Comment: really you'd be better off using fill="none" than fill="transparent" [none](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#SpecifyingPaint) is faster.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? fill="none" here changes it to red? https://jsfiddle.net/kc1muta6/ Can you provide further guidance?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the opacity in your  tag but as you will see in your example the blue shapes are over a red circle so I don't think adjusting the transparency will give the effect you are looking for.

`<path fill="blue" opacity="50%" d="m-101.116-101.116m169.705 11.313a113 113 0 00-137.178 0l68.589 68.59zm-158.392 21.214a113 113 0 000 137.178l68.59-68.589zm21.214 158.392a113 113 0 00137.178 0l-68.589-68.59zm158.392-21.214a113 113 0 000-137.178l-68.59 68.589z" />`

[image]

I suggest that you change the way you are creating the svg to punch out the blue shapes from the red shape and then export the svg this will give you the result you are looking for, unless you want only the red circle to display?

**Edit:** your graphic is being made up of the following shapes from left to right overlaying each other. The furthest image to the right is your final graphic made up of the other three. So making the blue transparent will display a red circle.

[image]

Comment: All I want to do is change the blue color to transparent.

Comment: Then either adding opacity="0" as I have suggested or changing fill="blue" to fill="transparent" as @Disala has suggested will work for you.

Comment: I have added an edit to my answer just to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.exit {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: circle(50%);

}

.exit svg {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
    <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <g id="exit">
            <title>exit</title>
            <path fill="red" d="m-101.116-101.116a143 143 0 11202.232 202.232a143 143 0 01-202.232-202.232zzzz" />
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="113" />
            <path fill="blue" d="m-101.116-101.116m169.705 11.313a113 113 0 00-137.178 0l68.589 68.59zm-158.392 21.214a113 113 0 000 137.178l68.59-68.589zm21.214 158.392a113 113 0 00137.178 0l-68.589-68.59zm158.392-21.214a113 113 0 000-137.178l-68.59 68.589z"  fill-opacity="0.3"/>
          </g>
   <!--You  can use   fill-opacity .This attribute takes a decimal number between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive; where 0.0 is completely transparent.-->      
        </svg>
      </button>

      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>

      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
```

Comment: That's not transparent, you can't see-through to the other side.

Comment: you can set the value of opacity ,as much as transparency you need .Pls read comment section ,I have added there.

Comment: 0.0 makes it red.

Comment: yeah it will, because blue get completely  transparent and red color will come because it is under the blue color that's why you are getting red color.

Comment: I don't want the red color.

Comment: then what color do u want?

Comment: To where the open spaces are completely see-through. https://i.imgur.com/V2EUkIT.png

Comment: change blue to white, you will get the result you want and tell me if you are not getting

Comment: White is not the same as transparent/ see-through.